# Can't connect to server with socket.io on both client and server

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, sockets, socket.io

I just started building me server using [socket.io](http://socket.io/) for both my client and `Node.js` server side.

I'm writing an `Objective-c` project so i walk through the process of adjusting my project to use `Swift` alongside with `Objective-c` which was a pain but it seems to be ok now.

The thing is, when i try to do a simple connect to my server, which prints to log on each connection, nothing happens.

This is the code for the server (Taken from [here](https://dzone.com/articles/getting-started-socketio-and)):

```
var fs = require('fs')
    , http = require('http')
    , socketio = require('socket.io');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-type': 'text/html'});
}).listen(8080, function() {
    console.log('Listening at: http://localhost:8080');
});

socketio.listen(server).on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Connected');
    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
        console.log('Message Received: ', msg);
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', msg);
    });
});
```

Super simple, really nothing to it.

And the `Objective-c` code for my client which is even more simple:

```
- (void) connect
{
    SocketIOClient* client = [[SocketIOClient alloc]initWithSocketURL:@"http://127.0.0.1:8080/" options:nil];
    [client connect];
}
```

But i can't see nothing on my console except the `Listening at: http://localhost:8080` message.

I can't seem to find what i'm doing wrong here, and the fact that the swift debugging is horrible in this combined project, i can't really fully go through the `socket.io` debugging myself (but i'm pretty sure nothing's wrong with their code)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

plz confirm, if you are using the simulator for iOS testing. For device, you need to assign public address to your NodeJS server, and then need to use it's ip in iOS Codebase.

I had used https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc during my last project and it worked like a charm.

For simulator, your code should ideally work.

Comment: Indeed, I am using simulator. so you are saying i have to use the server address as:
MyIP/8080 ?